# Problem trying to assign a value to a global variable in python

Tags: python, list, global

I'm trying to assign a value to a global list inside the function called "give_total_list" in python

```
total_list = list()

def give_total_list():
    global total_list //should I define the global variable here?
    big_list = glob.glob("drebin/feature_vectors/*")
    name_list = list()
    for el in big_list:
        single_directory_list = el.split("/")
        name = single_directory_list[2]
        name_list.append(name)

    total_list = list(name_list) 


def main():
   print (total_list)
   #when I print the list, it's void.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: how/where are you calling these 2 functions?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Python

Comment: Yes, but there should be some other lines in your code, something like `if __name__ == '__main__':` and then a call to these 2 functions....

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
total_list = list()

def give_total_list():
    global total_list //should I define the global variable here?
    big_list = glob.glob("drebin/feature_vectors/*")
    name_list = list()
    for el in big_list:
        single_directory_list = el.split("/")
        name = single_directory_list[2]
        name_list.append(name)

    total_list = list(name_list) 


def main():
   global total_list
   give_total_list() #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
   print (total_list)

main() #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

As soon as you call your function it should work.
Just defining a function (def ....) will only create it you still have to call it main() for example calls the main function